# Class Template Specialization for one Function

Tags: c++, c++17, sfinae

I've got a templated class that looks like this:

```
template<typename T>
class TemplatedClass
{
    // ... Other functions
    void AssignTo(const T & value)
    {
        m_value = value;
    }

private:
    T m_value;
    // ...
}
```

that I want to work with `std::atomic<>`, but doesn't at the moment because `std::atomic<>` is non-copyable.

Is there any way to only re-implement the `AssignTo()` function, but keep using all the other functions without modification so that we can have e.g. `TemplatedClass<std::atomic<bool>`? I've thought about using `std::enable_if` or template specialization, but haven't come up with an elegant solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
class TemplatedClass
{
public:
    void AssignTo(const T& value)
    {
        if constexpr (std::is_copy_assignable_v<T>) {
            m_value = value;
        } else {
            // Something else
        }
    }

private:
    T m_value;
};
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/863b6a48993824c5)

---

For atomic-only types, replace `std::is_copy_assignable_v<T>` with `!is_atomic_v<T>`:

```
template <typename>
constexpr bool is_atomic_v = false;

template <typename T>
constexpr bool is_atomic_v<std::atomic<T>> = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to only re-implement the `AssignTo()` function, but keep using all the other functions without modification so that we can have e.g. `TemplatedClass<std::atomic<bool>`?

Do you mean something as follows?

```
template <typename>
struct isAtomic : public std::false_type
 { };

template <typename T>
struct isAtomic<std::atomic<T>> : public std::true_type
 { };

template <typename T>
constexpr auto isAtomic_v = isAtomic<T>::value;

template <typename T>
class TemplatedClass
 {
    public: 
       // ... Other functions

       template <typename U = T>
       std::enable_if_t<false == isAtomic_v<U>> AssignTo(const T & value)
        { m_value = value; }

       template <typename U = T>
       std::enable_if_t<true == isAtomic_v<U>> AssignTo(const T & value)
        { /* ??? */ }

    private:
       T m_value;
    // ...
  };
```